# How to clean rdd or DataFrame with PySpark (drop nulls and duplicates)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I am new to Python/PySpark and I am having trouble cleansing the data before using it on my Mac's terminal. I want to delete any row that contains null values or repeated rows. I used `.distinct()` and tried with:

```
rw_data3 = rw_data.filter(rw_data.isNotNull())
```

I also tried...

```
from functools import reduce
rw_data.filter(~reduce(lambda x, y: x & y, [rw_data[c].isNull() for c in 
rw_data.columns])).show()
```

but I get

> `"AttributeError: 'RDD' object has no attribute 'isNotNull'"`

or

> `"AttributeError: 'RDD' object has no attribute 'columns'"`

Which clearly shows I do not really understand the syntax for cleaning up the DataFrame

Comment: Looks like you have an `rdd` and not a DataFrame. Try `print(type(rw_data3))` to find out for sure.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an `rdd`, and not a DataFrame. You can easily [convert the `rdd` to a DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39699107/spark-rdd-to-dataframe-python) and then use [`pyspark.sql.DataFrame.dropna()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.dropna) and [`pyspark.sql.DataFrame.dropDuplicates()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.dropDuplicates) to "clean" it.

```
clean_df = rw_data3.toDF().dropna().dropDuplicates()
```

Both of these functions accept and optional parameter `subset`, which you can use to specify a subset of columns to search for `null`s and duplicates.

---

If you wanted to "clean" your data as an `rdd`, you can use `filter()` and `distinct()` as follows:

```
clean_rdd = rw_data2.filter(lambda row: all(x is not None for x in row)).distinct()
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right. They are RDDs. Can I clean the RDDs as well? Or only the dataframes and then I have to convert them back into RDDs? Thanks again!

Comment: @lauvdb updated the answer for `rdd`s. You can operate on `rdd` but the DataFrame is [is generally preferred](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31508314/5858851), depending on [what you're trying to do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44317177/5858851).